# ansible - combine three lists of dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, ansible

In my playbook I'm gathering facts on applications, from multiple sources and end up with 3 (or more) lists, each of them have a dict.

Is there a way to combine such structure into one list of dictionaries. If not, any suggestion on how I would need to change the data structure?

My code that tries to combine **2 list-of-dict** (even that in final usecase there would be 3 or more).

All war_* lists should have the same number of dictionaries, with key "app_name", just arbitrarily we choose war_time as iterator - and **app_name** is common among  them all

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    war_status:
    - app_name: app1-SNAPSHOT
      app_status: running
    - app_name: app2
      app_status: stopped
    - app_name: app3-jsf
      app_status: unknown

    war_time:
    - app_name: app1-SNAPSHOT
      app_time: '2017-07-07 06:38:30'
    - app_name: app2
      app_time: '2018-07-19 09:16:57'
    - app_name: app3-jsf
      app_time: '2019-07-21 06:00:57'

    war_proxy_status:
    - app_name: app1-SNAPSHOT
      app_where_found: inst1
    - app_name: app2
      app_where_found: inst2
    - app_name: app3-jsf
      app_where_found: inst3

  tasks:

  - set_fact:
      war_combined: []

  - name: combine1 war_status and war_time
    set_fact:
      war_combined: "{{ war_combined | default([]) + [ war_status | combine( item ) ] }}"
    loop: "{{ war_time }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ war_combined }}"
```

The result I would like to achieve is:

```
war_combined:
- app_name: app1-SNAPSHOT
  app_status: running
  app_time: '2017-07-07 06:38:30'
  app_where_found: inst1
- app_name: app2
  app_status: stopped
  app_time: '2018-07-19 09:16:57'
  app_where_found: inst2
- app_name: app3-jsf
  app_status: unknown
  app_time: '2019-07-21 06:00:57'
  app_where_found: inst3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should combine individual elements, but you try merge single item into whole list.

Like this:

```
- set_fact:
    war_combined: >-
      {{ war_combined | default([])
         + [item | combine(time_item) | combine(proxy_item)]
      }}
  vars:
    time_item: >-
      {{ war_time
         | selectattr('app_name','equalto',item['app_name'])
         | list
         | first
      }}
    proxy_item: >-
      {{ war_proxy_status
         | selectattr('app_name','equalto',item['app_name'])
         | list
         | first
      }}
  loop: "{{ war_status }}"
```

We loop over `war_status` and use helper variables `time_item` and `proxy_item` that are evaluated for each iteration selecting specific element from lists with `app_name` matching current item's `app_name`.

Comment: Briliant answer, thanks. Unfortunately in my env I'm forced to use OS provided ansible and jinja. This grammar is not supported by RHEL6 (jinja 2.6 does not support selectattr) / RHEL7 (jinja 2.7 'equalto')

Comment: I'll rewrite list of dicts to nested dict.