# Ansible - Combining Lists of Dictionaries

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible

I have two lists of dictionaries. The first list of dict contains detailed information for all systems in an environment.

```yaml
"cluster_detail": [
    {
        "env_name": "env_1",
        "cluster_name": "cluster_1",
        "primary": "server1",
        "secondary": "server2,server3",
        "Standby": "server4,server5",
        "TieBreakers": "server6,server7"
    },
    {
        "env_name": "env_1",
        "cluster_name": "cluster_2",
        "primary": "server11",
        "secondary": "server12,server13",
        "Standby": "server14,server15",
        "TieBreakers": "server16,server17"
    },
    {
        "env_name": "env_2",
        "cluster_name": "cluster_7",
        "primary": "server21",
        "secondary": "server22,server23",
        "Standby": "server24,server25",
        "TieBreakers": "server26,server27"
    },
    {
        "env_name": "env_2",
        "cluster_name": "cluster_8",
        "primary": "server31",
        "secondary": "server32,server33",
        "Standby": "server34,server35",
        "TieBreakers": "server36,server37"
    }
]
```

The second list of dict contains partial detail for some parts of the same environment.

```yaml
"cluster_partial": [
    {
        "key": "env_1",
        "value": [
            "cluster_1",
            "cluster_2",
            "cluster_3",
            "cluster_4"
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "env_2",
        "value": [
            "cluster_5",
            "cluster_6",
            "cluster_7",
            "cluster_8"
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like to add detail to "cluster_partial" by searching for its values (cluster_1, Cluster_2, etc...) in "Cluster_detail", and where there's a match, add in the standby or tiebreaker server names.

I've been going through https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html and attempting various combinations of the examples given but am not having any success.

I've also looked at [ansible - combine three lists of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347555/ansible-combine-three-lists-of-dictionaries) but need to be more selective I think.

What I would like to end up with is

```yaml
{
  end_result:
    [
        {
            "key": "env_1",
            "value": [
                {
                    "cluster_1": {
                        "tiebreaker": [
                            "server6",
                            "server7"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "cluster_2": {
                        "tiebreaker": [
                            "server16",
                            "server17"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "cluster_3",
                "cluster_4"
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "env_2",
            "value": [
                "cluster_5",
                "cluster_6",
                {
                    "cluster_7": {
                        "tiebreaker": [
                            "server26",
                            "server27"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "cluster_8": {
                        "tiebreaker": [
                            "server36",
                            "server37"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Valid YAML

```yaml
  end_result:
    - key: env_1
      value:
      - cluster_1:
          tiebreaker: [server6, server7]
      - cluster_2:
          tiebreaker: [server16, server17]
      - cluster_3
      - cluster_4
    - key: env_2
      value:
      - cluster_5
      - cluster_6
      - cluster_7:
          tiebreaker: [server26, server27]
      - cluster_8:
          tiebreaker: [server36, server37]
```

---

I've tried the following

```yaml
- name: Add tiebreaker Value to list of Dictionary  
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    cluster_partial: |
        {% for item in cluster_partialm %}
        "tiebreaker": {{item}}
        {% endfor %}
    when: cluster_detail.cluster_name is defined and cluster_detail.cluster_name == cluster_partial.value`
```

Comment: The end result you gave as an example is not a valid json so it's hard to understand what you expect exactly.

Comment: It's also worth noting that in transforming `cluster_partial` you're attempting to replace a string value with a dictionary, which may complicate things. Do you have control over the structure of the input data?

Comment: I've fixed the *end_result* JSON. It's difficult to write valid JSON by hand. Why don't you use YAML instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the dictionary of available clusters

```yaml
  cluster_name_tiebreaker: "{{ cluster_detail|
                               items2dict(key_name='cluster_name',
                                          value_name='TieBreakers') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  cluster_name_tiebreaker:
    cluster_1: server6,server7
    cluster_2: server16,server17
    cluster_7: server26,server27
    cluster_8: server36,server37
```

Use Jinja to create the structure

```yaml
  end_result_str: |
    {% for e in cluster_partial %}
    {{ e.key }}:
    {% for cluster in e.value %}
    {% if cluster in cluster_name_tiebreaker %}
      {{ cluster }}:
        tiebreaker: {{ cluster_name_tiebreaker[cluster]|split(',') }}
    {% else %}
      {{ cluster }}:
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  end_result_dict: "{{ end_result_str|from_yaml }}"
```

gives the dictionary

```yaml
  end_result_dict:
    env_1:
      cluster_1:
        tiebreaker: [server6, server7]
      cluster_2:
        tiebreaker: [server16, server17]
      cluster_3: null
      cluster_4: null
    env_2:
      cluster_5: null
      cluster_6: null
      cluster_7:
        tiebreaker: [server26, server27]
      cluster_8:
        tiebreaker: [server36, server37]
```

Convert the dictionary to the list

```yaml
  end_result: "{{ end_result_dict|dict2items }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  end_result:
    - key: env_1
      value:
        cluster_1:
          tiebreaker: [server6, server7]
        cluster_2:
          tiebreaker: [server16, server17]
        cluster_3: null
        cluster_4: null
    - key: env_2
      value:
        cluster_5: null
        cluster_6: null
        cluster_7:
          tiebreaker: [server26, server27]
        cluster_8:
          tiebreaker: [server36, server37]
```

This is not exactly what you want. The attribute *value* is a dictionary. If you really want a list change the template

```yaml
    end_result_str: |
      {% for e in cluster_partial %}
      {{ e.key }}:
      {% for cluster in e.value %}
      {% if cluster in cluster_name_tiebreaker %}
        - {{ cluster }}:
            tiebreaker: {{ cluster_name_tiebreaker[cluster]|split(',') }}
      {% else %}
        - {{ cluster }}:
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  end_result:
    - key: env_1
      value:
      - cluster_1:
          tiebreaker: [server6, server7]
      - cluster_2:
          tiebreaker: [server16, server17]
      - {cluster_3: null}
      - {cluster_4: null}
    - key: env_2
      value:
      - {cluster_5: null}
      - {cluster_6: null}
      - cluster_7:
          tiebreaker: [server26, server27]
      - cluster_8:
          tiebreaker: [server36, server37]
```

Fit the template further if you really want to have various types of items in the lists. Remove the colon `:` to get strings instead of dictionaries with undefined (null) values

```yaml
      {% else %}
        - {{ cluster }}
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  end_result:
    - key: env_1
      value:
      - cluster_1:
          tiebreaker: [server6, server7]
      - cluster_2:
          tiebreaker: [server16, server17]
      - cluster_3
      - cluster_4
    - key: env_2
      value:
      - cluster_5
      - cluster_6
      - cluster_7:
          tiebreaker: [server26, server27]
      - cluster_8:
          tiebreaker: [server36, server37]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  
  vars:

    cluster_detail:
      - Standby: server4,server5
        TieBreakers: server6,server7
        cluster_name: cluster_1
        env_name: env_1
        primary: server1
        secondary: server2,server3
      - Standby: server14,server15
        TieBreakers: server16,server17
        cluster_name: cluster_2
        env_name: env_1
        primary: server11
        secondary: server12,server13
      - Standby: server24,server25
        TieBreakers: server26,server27
        cluster_name: cluster_7
        env_name: env_2
        primary: server21
        secondary: server22,server23
      - Standby: server34,server35
        TieBreakers: server36,server37
        cluster_name: cluster_8
        env_name: env_2
        primary: server31
        secondary: server32,server33

    cluster_partial:
      - key: env_1
        value: [cluster_1, cluster_2, cluster_3, cluster_4]
      - key: env_2
        value: [cluster_5, cluster_6, cluster_7, cluster_8]

    cluster_name_tiebreaker: "{{ cluster_detail|
                                 items2dict(key_name='cluster_name',
                                            value_name='TieBreakers') }}"
    end_result_str: |
      {% for e in cluster_partial %}
      {{ e.key }}:
      {% for cluster in e.value %}
      {% if cluster in cluster_name_tiebreaker %}
        - {{ cluster }}:
            tiebreaker: {{ cluster_name_tiebreaker[cluster]|split(',') }}
      {% else %}
        - {{ cluster }}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
    end_result_dict: "{{ end_result_str|from_yaml }}"
    end_result: "{{ end_result_dict|dict2items }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: cluster_name_tiebreaker
    - debug:
        var: end_result_str
    - debug:
        var: end_result_dict|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: end_result|to_yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `cluster_partial` is unnecessary for what you're doing; we can achieve something that almost matches your desired end state by using only the information in `cluster_detail`:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        end_result: >-
          {{
            end_result|combine({
              item.env_name: {
                item.cluster_name: {
                  "tiebreaker": item.TieBreakers.split(',')
                }
              }
            }, recursive=True)
          }}
      vars:
        end_result: {}
      loop: "{{ cluster_detail }}"

    - debug:
        var: end_result
```

Which produces:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "end_result": {
        "env_1": {
            "cluster_1": {
                "tiebreaker": [
                    "server6",
                    "server7"
                ]
            },
            "cluster_2": {
                "tiebreaker": [
                    "server16",
                    "server17"
                ]
            }
        },
        "env_2": {
            "cluster_7": {
                "tiebreaker": [
                    "server26",
                    "server27"
                ]
            },
            "cluster_8": {
                "tiebreaker": [
                    "server36",
                    "server37"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @larsks, unfortunately i need the "cluster_partial" list of dicts as that identifies systems that are managed by different systems and I need to be specific with these as they are prone to falling over if incorrect data is passed.
I'll try to use what you've provided and inject a loop of "cluster_partial" so that it extracts just the clusters that i need from "cluster_detail" when Cluster Names match. I'm guessing selectattr can be used for this ?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're asking, but you can use `selectattr` to filter a list based on attributes of items in the list. Does that sound like what you want?